# Single Kalman Filter: Resistance based on measurment of current and Voltage

Tags: discrete-signals, filter-design, kalman-filters, non-linear

Given measurement of voltage and current, which contain gaussian noise with known variance and a constant unknown offset $a_0$, I have attempted to estimate the resistance $R=\frac{V}{I}$. The assumption is that  current and voltage are both sinusoidal with the same frequency and phase shift. I discretized the following state model assuming a constant frequency:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -\omega^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}x(t)
\end{equation}

My first approach is the filtering of voltage and current through two seperate kalman filters given the following state and measurement model:
\begin{equation}
x_{k}
=\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos\omega T_s & \frac{\sin\omega T_s}{\omega} & 0 
\\ -\omega\sin\omega T_s & \cos\omega T_s &0
 \\ 0 & 0 &1  \end{bmatrix}x_{k-1}  
\end{equation}

where $$x=\begin{bmatrix}  A\sin(\omega t+\varphi) \\ A  \omega\cos(\omega t+\varphi) \\ a_0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $$y_{k}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}x_k.$$  So based on this formulation, I would have two identical Kalman filters, from which I can estimate the resistance through division of the output of both filters without any problem.

My goal now is to estimate everything within one kalman filter including the resistance $R$. Since  I am assuming that both signals are sinusoidal with same frequency and phase shift, the resistance would actually be the ratio of both amplitudes, and It would be constant in the period where the amplitude doesn't change. The thing is, the amplitude changes after a certain time interval, so the resistance would be piecewise constant.

I have used the following state space model and measurement model for the estimation:

\begin{equation}
x_{k}
=\begin{bmatrix}
   \cos\omega T_s & \frac{\sin\omega T_s}{\omega} & 0 & 0
\\ -\omega\sin\omega T_s & \cos\omega T_s &0& 0 
\\ 0 & 0 &1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}x_{k-1}  
\end{equation}
where $$x=\begin{bmatrix} A_I\sin(\omega t+\varphi) \\ A_I \omega \cos(\omega t+\varphi) \\ a_0 \\ R\end{bmatrix}$$  $$y_{k}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
                   0 & 0 & R_{pred,k} & I_{pred,k}   \end{bmatrix}x_k$$ and $$y=\begin{bmatrix} I_{meas,k} \\ V_{meas,k}   \end{bmatrix},$$ where $R_{pred,k}$ and $I_{pred,k}$ are the respective  resistance and current after the prediction step of the filter at time point $k$.

My choice of $P$,$Q$ and $R$ are as follows:
\begin{equation}
P
=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0& 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 &0& 0 
\\ 0 & 0 &0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
Q
=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0& 0 & 0
\\ 0 & 0 &0& 0 
\\ 0 & 0 &0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
R
=\begin{bmatrix}
  \sigma_I& 0
\\ 0 & \sigma_v \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

The estimation works initially fine, where the resistance hasn't yet changed, but when it does, the kalman filter doesn't respond correctly. It either doesn't respond as fast as needed or just diverge from the real measurement.

I have implemented the extended kalman filter to tackle the nonlinearity in the measurement model, but it didn't work. the measurement remain constant at a completely random value with no change, regardless of the change in resistance.

Comment: "The assumption is that current and voltage are both sinousodial", but your state change matrix is for a sinusoidal signal of known frequency with an unknown offset.  Why?

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to say what $R_{\mathrm{pred}, k}$ and $I_{\mathrm{pred},k}$ are.  Where do these numbers come from?  Presumably these are evolving over time -- how are they evolving over time?

Comment: In addition to Tim’s comments: I’m not sure where your transition matrix comes from? The usual [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) doesn’t have the extra $\omega$ terms on the sinusoidal entries.

Comment: "The usual rotation matrix doesn’t have the extra ω terms"  How did I miss that?

Comment: ok, I will detail my question further.

Comment: Are you sure you make no typos? For example, your very top fundamental matrix is missing a - sign infront of the $\omega^2$. Your (top) state $\bar{x}$ also does not look like $[x, \dot{x}]$ variant. Of course you are free to set your own state vector etc, but then further derivations should be inline... So this is a time-varying, linear (nonlinear?) passive (active?) resistance mesaurement..? From your explanation it looks as if the process (noise) model is the problem; i.e., filter cannot track when the resistance changes...

Comment: yes, thanks for the notice. I corrected the states definition

Comment: I'm afraid the edits confuse me even more. Can you explain what the state entries are in your original continuous-time $x(t)$?  The discretization step doesn't appear quite right, and it's not clear to me why a differential equation is needed to calculate resistance values. Impedance, I could understand, but resistance is just $\frac{V(t)}{I(t)}, \forall I(t) \not=0$

Comment: @PeterK. According to his statements, there's noise on the measured voltage / current samples hence direct division would yield erroneous results. So he probably wants to use the Kalman filter in noise reduction mode to improve the accuracy of calculated resistance values from the estimated values of noisy voltage and current measurements...

Comment: You have $R$ in the combined state, but also an **R** matrix (meas. noise cov. matrix?). Furthermore your combined discrete state transition matrix may still have a problem. A straight forward extension to the new state could be: $$\bar{x} = [ V, \dot{V}, I , \dot{I}, a_{0v}, a_{0i} ]^T$$ then your fund matrix will be :  $$ F = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -\omega^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\omega^2  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   \end{bmatrix} $$ Proceed from this, derive necessary matrices and see if it helps?

Comment: @Fat32 Right, but I can't figure out how to get there from where the updated post is.